# Completable must complete when an observable's on next is fired

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an `Observable` as follows:

```java
    public Observable<List<Object>> getObjectsForUser() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            if (objects.size() < 1) {
                List<ObjectDto> dtos = dataSource.getAllForUser();
                if (dtos != null) {
                    objects = objectMapper.toDomain(dtos);
                }
            }
            return objects;
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
```

Which is used in this way:

```java
    public Completable refreshOtherObjects() { // How do I return a completable which completes when the code in this lambda Observer has finished execution? 
        objectRepository.getObjectsForUser().subscribe(objects -> {
                for (Object object: objects) {
                    List<OtherObjectDto> dtos = dataSource.getOtherObjects(object.getId());
                    if (dtos != null) {
                        otherObjectDao.upsertOtherObjects(mapper.toEntity(dtos));
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

My question is:

How do I return a completable which completes when the code in the lambda Observer in the last described method has finished execution?

Comment: As an aside, I would recommend returning `Single<List<Object>>` instead of `Observable<List<Object>>` from `getObjectsForUser`, since that method will only ever emit a single element, or fail. It makes the semantics of your API clearer if you use `Single` in that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of nesting a `subscribe` call inside of `refreshOtherObjects`, continue the Rx chain by just doing that work inside of a `.doOnNext` call, and then convert the chain to a `Completable` using the `ignoreElements()` operator:

```java
   public Completable refreshOtherObjects() { // How do I return a completable which completes when the code in this lambda Observer has finished execution? 
        return objectRepository.getObjectsForUser()
            .doOnNext(objects -> {
                for (Object object: objects) {
                    List<OtherObjectDto> dtos = dataSource.getOtherObjects(object.getId());
                    if (dtos != null) {
                        otherObjectDao.upsertOtherObjects(mapper.toEntity(dtos));
                    }
                }
            })
            .ignoreElements();
    }
```